# Is it necessary to fetch upstream before create a pull request on github?

Tags: git, github

I was wondering when do i need to fetch upstream and merge it to development? only before i start working on a branch or i should also do it when i want to push my changes?

I mean if i have some loval changes and i want to push them and create a pull request but meanwhile there was some changes done by others to server. so should i merge upstream before i push or not?

because when i do it before push it added some  changes that needed to be commit.

> All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
>     (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Comment: Your title and description and last two sentences are actually different questions, but yes, it is generally good practice to sync with upstream before creating a pull request.  In fact, some of the time you won't even be able to create a PR without first pulling.

Comment: Although it *is* good practice, it is not *necessary* if the changes made on the branch you want to merge into do not conflict with your own.